# Post request handling with lua script in nginx

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I use lua script to generate data from the parameters and bodies, and then send the data to the other server.

When i handle a GET request, nginx returns a normal response.

However, a 404 not found error occurs when handling POST requests.

However, internal operations were normal and sent the data to the other server.

Only the request method has changed.

If i explicitly pass the value to ngx.say or ngx.exit, i get 200 response normally.

Why? Is it necessary to explicitly return a response code when using a post request with a lua script?

In addition, I am using empty_gif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched for the above problem.

empty_gif can only be used to respond to GET and HEAD request methods

so I will use 204 response code